# Leer tabla de una url con R

Tags: base-de-datos, r, url

tengo problemas con la función read.table. Quiero leer una tabla de una url, y guardarla en R como un dataframe. La url es: https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt

He escrito este código:

```
library(RCurl)

a <- getURL('https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt')
b = read.table(a, sep="\t ", header = TRUE, nrows=3)

download.file("https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt","/mnt/M/Ana Rubio/R/datos_treemap.txt",method = c("wget"))
```

Pero no consigo que los datos se guarden como dataframe, y me sale el error siguiente:

```
[1] "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>302 Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Found</h1>\n<p>The document has moved <a href=\"https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt\">here</a>.</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) Server at datanalytics.com Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n"
```

También he intentado descargargme el archivo como un txt y guardarlo en mi ordenador, pero se me genera un txt con la tabla en una sola fila. El código que he utilizado es:

```
download.file("https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt","/mnt/M/Ana Rubio/R/datos_treemap.txt",method = c("wget"))
```

Alguien sabe qué errores estoy cometiendo? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ana:

El problema aparece, en algunos sistemas, con las conexiones "HTTPS". Usa el método "curl", en "download.file", para descargar el dataset en lugar de "wget". Sería algo así:

```
download.file("https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt", "datos_treemap.txt", "curl")
df<-read.table("datos_treemap.txt", header=T)
class(df) #[1] "data.frame"
View(df)
```

[image: Vista del dataframe]

Comment: Muchas gracias, de esta forma ya funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Ana, no necesitas descargar el archivo mediante `download.file` ya que [`read.table`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) puede recibir y procesar directamente la url,

> file can also be a complete URL. (For the supported URL schemes, see
>   the ‘URLs’ section of the help for url.)

por ejemplo:

```
b = read.table("https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE, nrows=3)
```

Modifiqué también el parámetro `sep` ya que tenías un espacio de más y solo acepta un solo caracter.

Comment: Hola Patricio, me sigue saliendo un error:  Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : unsupported URL scheme